# How to draw a landscape without using millions triangles in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have created the program (C++/OpenGL) which generates landscape using OpenSimplex noise and drawing it as one mesh (so I have to call draw function only once per frame). I am using `glDrawElements` function. The mesh contains 1023 * 1023 rectangles = 1023 * 1023 * 2 triangles, and the landscape looks like in PS1 games and using over 500 mb of RAM. How can I make smooth landscape (like in modern games) without using so many triangles?

Edit: Would it be effecient to have few VBO's, which are differently detailed, and draw nearest triangles from the most detailed VBO, farer from less detailed etc?

Comment: Do you know Level of Detail? https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/6na49n/how_does_lod_work/

Comment: I don't think that changing the model every draw call will be effecient. The problem is not in draw performance, but in amount of triangles for this landscape, which is not detailed

Comment: 250 bytes per triangle sounds at least ten times too much.

Comment: I have optimized it using EBO, so now this program totally takes about 150 mb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern games typically use a series of techniques to render high quality scenery.

1. View-Frustum culling *(throw away triangles that are not on screen)*. This usually involves splitting your GEO into a number of smaller chunks that can be ignored when they are not visible on screen.
2. Geo Mip-Mapping *(Replace far away geo with lower LOD versions, and near GEO with high res versions)*. Often this just involves re-using a predefined set of indices for given LODS *(where the underlying vertex data stays the same, but the index data specifies every vert for the highest lod, every other vertex for the second lod, every 4th vertex for the 3rd lod, and so on)*
3. Tessellation shaders *(add more triangles to a bit of GEO to smooth off the rough edges)*
4. Bump/Normal mapping *(or other per-pixel lighting effects)*. Use texture data to add more surface variation to a triangle being rendered.

Basically, if you want smooth GEO, you're going to need to add either

1. more triangles, or
2. additional texture data (e.g. normal or displacement maps).

The trick is minimising the amount the triangles you need to render a given frame, rather than worrying about how many triangles you have in total.

p.s. 1024 * 1024 * vec3 is 18Mb of vertex data (+18Mb of normal data, +24Mb of index data). These days we have Gigs of ram available for the GPU, so a few megs is not that big of a deal. Again, Geo-Mipmapping will reduce the amount of index data down to a minimum.

Comment: I am already using first method and heard about others, except tesselation. I will read about this method more and will try to implement it

Comment: I'd suggest that Geo-Mipmapping is probably the technique you want to be looking into first....

Comment: Would it be effecient to have few VBO's, which are differently detailed, and draw nearest triangles from the most detailed VBO, farer from less detailed etc?